# Core ML model class not getting generated in App Playground Xcode

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-playground, coreml, xcode15

I am trying to use the `SqueezeNet coreML` model, but it says that model is not part of any target and to add the model to a target to enable the model class generation. I can not add it to a target because I am using an app playground in Xcode. Also, I need to use app playgrounds not an Xcode project. I have to use it because I want to submit my project to the **WWDC** Swift Student Challenge and they only accept `.swiftpm` files.

I have tried to compile the `.mlmodel` in an Xcode project and move it the app playground. Also I have tried accessing the code for the `coreML` model, but I was not able to.